# How to vectorize a function within loop with break in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to run the following program with numpy vector code within **loop** with **break** in Python 3 but get `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous` because of the "if" (it's ok to compare a numpy array to a scalar as each element is compared to the scalar)
How would this be possible to run it in a vectorized way ?
The issue is managing the break within the loop.

Below a dummy program:

```
import numpy as np

THRESHOLD=0.5
ARRAY_LEN =10

def inner_compute():
    pass

def compute(draws):
    return draws /2

calculation = np.zeros(ARRAY_LEN)
for i in range(5):
    draws = np.random.uniform(0, 1, ARRAY_LEN)
    if draws < THRESHOLD:
        #    if above ^ creates a ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
        calculation += compute(draws)
        break
    #use np.vectorize and call inner_compute?
    
print (f"calculation {calculation}")
```

Comment: Hey! Can you specify by editing the question what you are trying to achieve (e.g. explaining in words what the code should do)? In the `if` condition you are comparing an array of floats to `0.5` so indeed it's not clear under which conditions you want the body in the `if` to be executed. Do you want to execute the code only for the elements of `draws` below the THRESHOLD? What's the purpose that `break` is trying to achieve?

Comment: What is `if draws < THRESHOLD` actually supposed to be determining?

Answer (score 1):

You question was unclear.

The symptom you experience is clear and easy to avoid.
It sounds like you may want to compute an aggregate over the booleans.
An `if` could then make a decision based on the aggregate.

```
>>> ARRAY_LEN = 8
>>> calculation = np.zeros(ARRAY_LEN)
>>> calculation < THRESHOLD
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
>>> 
>>> sum(calculation < THRESHOLD)
8
```